# software development under chromeOS?

Tags: vim, eclipse, development

Will I be able to do software development (scala, java, python, ruby, etc.) when I'm using the chromeOS? What are the development environments gonna be like? Currently I use vim, bash, and eclipse primarily. Will these be available?

Comment: ssh to your dev system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Desktop environments like Eclipse will only be available through remote desktop/VNC/Citrix apps (to another actual/virtualized desktop). For the "pure" Chrome OS experience, you'll need to use new cloud-based development sites/apps like [Kodingen](http://kodingen.com/). With basic offline capability, you'll be able to edit code and maybe manage your project without live connectivity, but not compile it -- until someone writes compilers in JavaScript or something. Perhaps Google's [NaCl](http://code.google.com/p/nativeclient/) will fill that gap.

The current Cr-48 prototype lets you drop into a (custom, not bash) shell. You can do some work there, but I have not heard whether and how a shell will be available on the final consumer units, and how Google might try to mandate what is or is not there. Regardless, if you can get full root access, you can install whatever you want on top of the Linux base; but I would not consider that to be "Chrome OS" any more.

Comment: Something you have to remember is that when you're in developer mode (When you flip the switch behind the battery), you have access to a bash shell. Not much that you can do with it *out of the box* for development, but you've got it.

Answer (score 5):

a pretty accurate list of packages chrome has out of the box can be found here: http://virtguru.wordpress.com/2010/09/22/12minutes-chromium-os-internals-installed-packages-and-their-sizes-on-defaut-devel-image/

it's just a JeOS customization so ultimately you should be able to put pretty much any linux package on it imo.  i don't see a jre out of the box for eclipse, but vim and bash are both there.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome OS is sometimes regarded as a limited operating system capable of nothing more than web browsing. Contrary to popular assumption, Chromebooks are capable and efficient laptops that will even outperform macOS in the second half of 2020, with speed and security ranking first, according to statistics.

Here are some details about the numerous code editors available on Chrome OS, as well as how to access or install them on your device.

1: Using Linux and Code Editors to Program

2: Using Web-Based Applications to Program on Chromebooks

3: DroidScript on the Google Play Store